# Instanced extension methods? C#

Tags: c#, extension-methods

So I would like to create an extension method for a Type that the api has otherwise sealed.

If you know about extension methods the following should look familiar.

```
private static List<Member> memberList = new List<Member>();

public static List<Member> GetMemberList(this GameObject go)
{
    return memberList;
}
```

Notice that to declare an extension method, it needs to be static, and because it needs to be static, the List that Im accessing through the GameObject type has to be static to. 
I would like each GameObject to have its own list of Members. However Im pretty sure since this is a static field every instanced GameObject will point to the same static memberList.

So would my assumptions be true? And if so, what might be an alternative? I would like to avoid putting the GameObject in a wrapper class that also holds the memberList because the api only allows GameObjects to be detected and manipulated at runtime. There are ways to reverse reference the wrapper class through the gameObject but that adds a lot more complexity to the code i would like to avoid.

Comment: You'll call `GetMemberList` on a `GameObject` instance, and it will return that instance's list. I don't think I see the problem. (The extension method is static, and must be declared in a static type, but the "extended" `this` parameter is an instance.)

Comment: That was my question if that would happen. Also I just read this from another website "Extension methods are a special kind of static method, but they are called as if they were instance methods on the extended type." But what about the static memberList? its a static field accessed from the extension method.

Comment: @DanJ: The problem is that the member list is not a part of the game object.

Comment: Extension methods aren't really special at all, except for the fact that they can be treated as if they're methods on the class you're extending. They're still plain old static methods, and anything static that they touch is still global.

Comment: @Guffa Ah, I misunderstood. I read "I would like each GameObject to have its own list of Members" and then ignored the presence of the static `memberList`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you are working with Unity3. There is a related answer on the UnityAnswers site that may help: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/22493/unity-3-sealed-class-gameobject-.html

It appears that there should be ways to attach the behaviors you want inherent in the Unity framework using the builtin scripting system.

Comment: +1 for being Psychic!, I completely forgot about components. I would of asked this at unity answers but I thought this was a pure C# problem.

Comment: A great solution ended up being to attach a component to the game object with an instanced version of the List, and then to use the extension method as a read friendly way to access it. Thanks to @Jan for pointing out that extension methods can only extend behaviors and not data. That helped me realize this.

Comment: So, googling sealed class GameObject was a good starting point for looking psychic.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, if you want to keep something outside the game object and access it through the extension method, it would have to be static.

You can use a dictionary to map one member list to each game object:

```
private static Dictionary<GameObject, List<Member>> memberLists = new Dictionary<GameObject, List<Member>>();

public static List<Member> GetMemberList(this GameObject go) {
  return memberLists[go];
}
```

Comment: +1 Though I thought I'd mention - Use care if you do this, as the static dictionary will keep all items in lists, as well as the GameObject instances reachable by the GC, so they'll never get GCed.  Make sure your `GameObject` instances remove themselves correctly if you use this approach, or you'll likely get memory issues.

Comment: this is very interesting, Im going to try it out right now. Also @Reed Copsey , very good point. Ill keep this in mine as I figure out the proper solution to this.

Comment: As well as the GC issues, and that it will throw KeyNotFoundException on the first call, it's not thread-safe.

Comment: @JonHanna: I think that you mean that the method will not find a key that you haven't put in the dictionary, which is pretty obvious. As long as you add a list for each game objects to the dictionary, it won't throw any exception. The thread safety is a good point though. You would need to add some synchronisation if it's accessed from more than one thread at a time.

Comment: Yes, but to put the new list in the dictionary, you need to know you need to put the new list in the dictionary. Unless all GameObject's come from a single factory method that also adds the new list, this would also need to be dealt with in this call.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right. If you have a static method, all instances of that class share the same data. The call `return memberList;` is illegal. It is the same as `return this.memberList;` and `this` is not available in a static method. Instead you'd have to call the class: `return GameObject.memberList;`. But I understand that you are not looking for this solution.

Extension methods are meant to create additional **behavior**. If you want to create additional **data**, extending the GameObject class using inheritance is the right choice.

Alternatively you could attach the memberList by using a dictionary of the form `Dictionary<GameObject, List<Member>>`. But personally I'd favor composition as shown below:

```
public class myGameObject
{
    public List<Member> memberList { get; set; }
    public GameObject go { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Several problems with this answer, Jan. 1/ return memberList is a legal statement (not a call), but will return the classes static member, not an instance member. It is definitely not equivalent to return this.memberList. 2/ Extending a sealed class is not possible, but a wrapper class using composition would be, but if it is to be consumed by a framework that expects an instance of GameObject, you're not going to have good results.

Comment: unfortunately inheriting from the gameObject cant be done as its been sealed from the api. To get around this problem in the past Ive created wrapper classes similier to what you have shown. But it adds a lot of additional complexity Id like to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static ConditionalWeakTable<GameObject, List<Member>> dict = new ConditionalWeakTable<GameObject, List<Member>>();

public static List<Member> GetMemberList(this GameObject go)
{
  return dict.GetOrCreateValue(go);
}
```

`ConditionalWeakTable` manages the object lifetime, because it uses weak-references. Therefore it doesn't stop the GC from collecting the `GameObject` if it there are no other live references to it, and this will also allow the `List<Member>` to be collected.

It is threadsafe, but this assumes that you want your starting point to be an empty list (the default constructor is called in `GetOrCreateValue` if there isn't a current value). If you want a different starting point, your threading issues become more complicated.

Comment: This is a great alternative as well, I have a lot of options to try out.

Comment: Tetsujin no Oni's seems like the soundest bet, though I know nothing about unity myself.

Answer (score 0):

Extension methods are simply just static methods that "appear" to look like instance methods.

They however, do not add any additional functionality a static method doesn't, it's just for ease-of-use, maintenance, and readability.  Extension methods cannot access protected / private members either.

If `GameObject` is not actually sealed (ie it doesn't have the `sealed` keyword), then you can write a class that inherits `GameObject` to gain access to its protected methods/fields/properties.  This will only work if you yourself are the one constructing these objects.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately inheriting from a GameObject is off limits and i have no access to change it.